# How did we do in the Private Beta?

Tags: discussion, private-beta

Now that the site has moved from Private Beta to Public Beta, are we going to be able to see any statistics as to how the site is performing?

I know there are statistics at [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/60887/software-recommendations) but that doesn't show how we compare to other Private Betas.  There has certainly been a lot of activity over the last week and it would be very interesting to know if this is typical or an indication that this site will fly.

I also understand that the powers that be within StackExchange may not wish to give out information that may be commercially sensitive.

Comment: We're in public beta? [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/60887/software-recommendations) says we are still in private.

Comment: We actually aren't in private beta..

Comment: People can log into this site without using the key in the Private Beta invitation email, so it must be Public now.  I'm sure Area51 will catch up in good time.

Comment: Huh. Alrighty then.

Comment: This site *is* in private beta. See **[Can we have another week in private beta?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/308/an-odd-request-can-we-have-another-week-in-private-beta/399#399)**

Comment: cc @aman207 . There was a recent change that let anyone who came from Area51 to create an account even if the site was in private beta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different sites face different challenges.

A lack of traffic is clearly not one of our problems. This site has had more questions than most private betas.

We knew right off the bat that the main challenge of this site would be quality, not quantity. Quality is difficult to measure with metrics. [We requested another week in private beta](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308/an-odd-request-can-we-have-another-week-in-private-beta) precisely so that we could refine our quality expectations (for [questions](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) and [answers](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356/what-is-required-for-an-answer-to-be-high-quality)) and figure out [how to perform quality control](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/305/how-are-we-going-to-moderate-answers).